# Process only first file received in a batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, batch-processing

From a bunch of files received over a period of time, I want to process each file sequentially in First In First Out manner.The file names are suffixed with sequence no. in the order they were received. Files names would be like: 100_abc.txt, 101_pqr.txt, 103_xyz.txt and so on... Need help in writing some logic in batch file to process only the first file(100_abc.txt in this case) out of these files. Then repeat the same batch for next processing and then process 101pqr.txt

What command should be used within a batch file to pick up the 1st file received from a bunch of files and then repeat the same for remaining files one by one?

Comment: And, what is the criteria used to determine, from a bunch of files, what is the first? Date created, date modified, size, ...?

Comment: How does a batch-file “receive” files? Are they arguments?

Comment: Also - what is the date/time format your system uses?

Comment: The criteria for determining the file would be date created/date modified.

Comment: The files are not "received" by batch file but are placed at a location. Btach file needs to just move the file one after other on First In First Out basis to other location

Comment: Sorry missed something earlier, the file names are suffixed with sequence no. in the order they were received. Files names would be like: 100_abc.txt, 101_pqr.txt, 103_xyz.txt and so on... Need help in writing some logic in batch file to process only the first file(100_abc.txt in this case) out of these files. Then repeat the same batch for next processing and then process 101pqr.txt

Comment: Have you tried anything before posting this question? Do you have some code that we can take a look at?

Comment: Also, why is important that they are moved in order?

Answer (score 0):

This will move them by modified date, oldest to newest.

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\holding\folder"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /od') do move"%%a" "d:\elsewhere"
pause
```